# Postgres COPY TO PROGRAM with dynamic command

Tags: postgresql, triggers, command

I have command that I want to execute after insert in table `event`, the command is:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/app/artisan broadcast --sid=14 --cid=89
```

Which number *14* and *89* are dynamic depending on inserted data.

For that purpose, I create trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_event 
AFTER INSERT ON event 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE call_artisan_broadcast();
```

And I create trigger function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION call_artisan_broadcast()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN

    COPY (SELECT 1) TO PROGRAM '/usr/bin/php /var/www/app/artisan broadcast --sid='||NEW.sid||' --cid='||NEW.cid;
    RETURN NEW;
  END
$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

That trigger produce error

```
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "||"
```

This trigger work fine if the command not have concatenation. I do not know how to concatenate command string with variable `NEW` in **COPY TO PROGRAM**.

My question is how to concatenate string in `COPY TO PROGRAM` in trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
EXECUTE format('COPY (SELECT 1) TO PROGRAM ''/usr/bin/php /var/www/app/artisan broadcast --sid=%s --cid=%s'' ', NEW.sid, NEW.cid);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this not work, it is produce error `42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "FORMAT"`

Comment: @FathurRohman In that case the command expects a string literal. You could try wrapping the entire statement in an `EXECUTE` command. See updated answer.